# Not able to add Rabbitmq plugin

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt

I was following this http://www.rabbitmq.com/plugin-development.html link to build rabbitmq plugin https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-web-mqtt

after building i ONLY copied `rabbitmq_mqtt.ez` to `/usr/lib/rabbitmq/lib/rabbitmq_server-3.6.2/plugins`

running `sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_web_mqtt`
shows :

```
The following plugins have been enabled:
  cowlib
  cowboy
  rabbitmq_web_mqtt

Applying plugin configuration to rabbit@manish-Lenovo-G510... failed.
Error: {could_not_start,rabbitmq_web_mqtt,
           {undef,
               [{lager_config,get,
                    [{rabbit_log_lager_event,loglevel},{0,[]}],
                    []},
                {rabbit_web_mqtt_app,mqtt_init,0,
                    [{file,"src/rabbit_web_mqtt_app.erl"},{line,69}]},
                {rabbit_web_mqtt_app,start,2,
                    [{file,"src/rabbit_web_mqtt_app.erl"},{line,31}]},
                {application_master,start_it_old,4,
                    [{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,269}]}]}}
```

Running `sudo rabbitmq-plugins list`

```
 Configured: E = explicitly enabled; e = implicitly enabled
 | Status:   * = running on rabbit@manish-Lenovo-G510
 |/
[e*] amqp_client                       3.6.2
[e ] cowboy                            1.0.3
[e ] cowlib                            1.0.1
[e*] mochiweb                          2.13.1
[  ] rabbitmq_amqp1_0                  3.6.2
[  ] rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap        3.6.2
[  ] rabbitmq_auth_mechanism_ssl       3.6.2
[  ] rabbitmq_consistent_hash_exchange 3.6.2
[  ] rabbitmq_event_exchange           3.6.2
[  ] rabbitmq_federation               3.6.2
[  ] rabbitmq_federation_management    3.6.2
[E*] rabbitmq_management               3.6.2
[e*] rabbitmq_management_agent         3.6.2
[  ] rabbitmq_management_visualiser    3.6.2
[E*] rabbitmq_mqtt                     3.6.2
[  ] rabbitmq_recent_history_exchange  1.2.1
[  ] rabbitmq_sharding                 0.1.0
[  ] rabbitmq_shovel                   3.6.2
[  ] rabbitmq_shovel_management        3.6.2
[  ] rabbitmq_stomp                    3.6.2
[  ] rabbitmq_tracing                  3.6.2
[e*] rabbitmq_web_dispatch             3.6.2
[E ] rabbitmq_web_mqtt                 
[  ] rabbitmq_web_stomp                3.6.2
[  ] rabbitmq_web_stomp_examples       3.6.2
[  ] sockjs                            0.3.4
[e*] webmachine                        1.10.3
```

I am not able to connect using paho JS client. So what is causing the issue? I tried port 1888, 8083,8883,15675

Comment: I think You have built the version based on `master` branch, you should build the version for the version `3.6.2`

Comment: i disnt get you. can u explain bit more pleas

Comment: Check this [http://stackoverflow.com/a/38452053/1515447](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38452053/1515447)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Applying plugin configuration to rabbit@manish-Lenovo-G510... failed.
Error: {could_not_start,rabbitmq_web_mqtt,
           {undef,
               [{lager_config,get,
```

Lager is only in the version `3.7.0`, most likely you built the `master` branch.

To build the plugin version `3.6.2` you should:

```
    git clone https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-public-umbrella.git .
    make up BRANCH=rabbitmq_v3_6_2
    cd deps/rabbitmq_web_mqtt
    make dist
```

**EDIT**

you have to disable and remove the old `.ez` file, after copied the new one, you have to enable the plugin.

just tried and it works correctly, see the test:

[image]

Comment: I copied binary `rabbitmq_web_mqtt-3.6.x-3b6a09bb.ez` from `https://www.rabbitmq.com/community-plugins.html` and copied to `/usr/lib/rabbitmq/lib/rabbitmq_server-3.6.2/plugins` but i am getting ` 'ws://127.0.0.1:15675/mqtt' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Comment: but paho client send request as `ws://localhost:15675/mqtt`

Comment: @manish this is another question/problem. Please accept the answer if it is ok and maybe ask another one. I am not `Paho` expert but I am almost sure you can change the end point